# Как сделать выпадающий список произвольной формы?

Tags: wpf, xaml, style

Здравствуйте, хотел бы узнать, как решить эту проблему. Есть элемент `Expander`, который имеет свой стандартный стиль. Использование `Data` или `Path` даёт возможно изменить внешний вид окна и саму кнопку для активации этого выпадающего списка при использование `Template`. Как это возможно сделать и также чтобы выпадающий список был ровно под кнопкой? К примеру: вызов окна в Skype `Данные о качестве связи`(громкость и тд.).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Note:** знаю, как использовать  Data и Path.

Comment: Вам нужен именно Popup (который есть отдельное _окно_), или inline-элемент наподрбие Expander?

Comment: Всё-таки дополнительное окно `Popup`, которое будет отображаться поверх другого окна в котором находится,
закрывая другие элементы, а не inline-элемент. Таким образом, чтобы при нажатии, происходила плавное открытие,
как в `Expander`, если это конечно можно регулировать с помощью `Duration`.Также плавное направление открытия(с вверху вниз, с низу вверх и тд.), как у `Expander` или с угла к другому углу. Как это возможно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если надо можно будет дорисовать `^` самому, так как `Path` точно прорисован по контуру.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="PopupToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="32"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="32"/>
            <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="32"/>
            <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="32"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 5 0 0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse_popup">
                                <Ellipse.Fill>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF8B8B8B"/>
                                </Ellipse.Fill>
                            </Ellipse>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="ellipse_popup" Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="ellipse_popup" Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ButtonBase.IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="ellipse_popup" Property="Stroke" Value="#FF343434"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="ellipse_popup" Property="Fill" Value="#FFC7C7C7"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="ellipse_popup" Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="Popup_style" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Grid Width="180" Height="Auto" >
                        <Path Panel.ZIndex="1" Stroke="Orange" StrokeThickness="0.02" 
        Data="M11.3,0 L11.3,0 L168.5,0 A12,12 0 0 1 179.99,12 L179.99,78.5 A12,12 0 0 1 168.5,90 L11.3,90 A12,12 0 0 1 0,78.5 L0,12 A12,12 0 0 1 11.3,0 z "/>
                        <Border Background="#FF646464" CornerRadius="12">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="Popup_button" Margin="0 40 0 0"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      Style="{StaticResource PopupToggleButton}"/>
    <Popup StaysOpen="True" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Popup_button, Mode=TwoWay}" 
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Popup_button}" 
               AllowsTransparency="True"
               PopupAnimation="Slide"
               HorizontalOffset="-75"
               VerticalOffset="0">
        <ContentControl Style="{DynamicResource Popup_style}">
            <StackPanel Margin="5 10 5 5" >
                <Button Content="Click1" Width="120" Margin="0"/>
                <Button Content="Click2" Width="120" Margin="0 5 0 0"/>
                <Button Content="Click3" Width="120" Margin="0 5 0 0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ContentControl>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```